# Process.Start Help in Java

Tags: c#, java, process, arguments

Is it possible to do the following C# Code in Java?

```
Process.Start("c:/test.exe", "filearg1,filearg2,filearg3");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) classes.

You can use something like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("c:/test.exe filearg1,filearg2,filearg3");
```

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec({"c:/test.exe", "filearg1", "filearg2"}, envP, dir);

Comment: 15 seconds of reading the referenced Runtime class doc quickly reveals: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:/test.exe", "filearg1", "filearg2", "filearg3"});

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you read ["When Runtime.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is the recommended way of managing external processes since Java 5.
There is a nicer interface for manipulating environment variables, and an option to automatically redirect standard error to standard output.

Unfortunately, as with Runtime.exec() you still have to manually start up a thread to consume processes output stream (and error stream) to prevent it from blocking the system.